# How to implement polling in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I want to use Airflow to implement data flows that periodically poll external systems (ftp servers, etc), check for new files matching certain conditions, and then run a bunch of tasks for those files. Now, I'm a newbie to Airflow and read that Sensors are something you would use for this kind of a case, and I actually managed to write a sensor that works ok when I run "airflow test" for it. But I'm a bit confused regarding the relation of poke_interval for the sensor and the DAG scheduling. How should I define those settings for my use case? Or should I use some other approach? I just want Airflow to run the tasks when those files become available, and not flood the dashboard with failures when no new files were available for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, using a sensor is the way to go when you want to poll, either by using an existing sensor or by implementing your own.

They are, however, always part of a DAG and they do not execute outside of its boundaries. DAG execution depends on the `start_date` and `schedule_interval`, but you can leverage this and a sensor to implement some sort of DAG depending on the status of an external server: one possible approach would be starting the whole DAG with a sensor which checks for a condition to occur and decide to skip the whole DAG if the condition is not met (you can make sure that sensors mark downstream tasks as `skipped` and not `failed` by setting their `soft_fail` parameter to `True`). You can have a polling interval of one minute by using the most frequent scheduling option (`* * * * *`). If you *really* need a shortest polling time you can tweak the sensor's `poke_interval` and `timeout` parameters.

Keep in mind, however, that execution times are not probably guaranteed by Airflow itself, so for very short polling times you may want to investigate alternatives (or at least consider different approaches to the one I've just shared).

Comment: Using soft_fail=True seems to do the trick and keep my DAG dashboard free from unnecessary errors, so I'm accepting this answer. For the scheduling I'll just use the DAG scheduling and then time out the sensor after a couple of quick pokes. My polling schedules are usually hourly or daily so I guess that should do it. Or are there any gotchas there?

Comment: No, hourly schedules are absolutely more then fine.